# Social media links showing blank page

Tags: html, twitter, anchor, social-media

I am trying to add some social media links to my web page inside CodePen but clicking the link gives a blank page.

For example:

```
<div class="col-md-2"><a href="https://twitter.com/Mr_Cool_Web"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></div>
```

This URL just leads to a blank white page. My website is accessible [here](https://codepen.io/dave-bage/full/WJazNm/). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post more of your HTML code.

Comment: Adding the code of `<head>` would be great too. Are you using any JS code?

Comment: Actually I'm doing this as a practice codepen project - just part of the freecodecamp course. Here's the codepen link: https://codepen.io/dave-bage/full/WJazNm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodePen displays your webpage in an `iframe`. `iframe`s allow you to embed another web page inside another web page<sup>[1]</sup>. When you click a link inside an `iframe`, the new web page will be displayed inside that `iframe`.

However, you can prevent a web page or web site to be displayed inside an `iframe`. You just need to set the `X-Frame-Options` to `'deny'` and your page will no longer be displayed in an `iframe`, `frame`, or `object`. This is used as a security measure against [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking)<sup>[2]</sup>.

Wikipedia defines *clickjacking* as<sup>[3]</sup>

> Clickjacking is a malicious technique of tricking a Web user into
>   clicking on something different from what the user perceives they are
>   clicking on, thus potentially revealing confidential information or
>   taking control of their computer while clicking on seemingly innocuous
>   web pages.
>
> A clickjacked page tricks a user into performing undesired actions by
>   clicking on a concealed link. On a clickjacked page, the attackers
>   load another page over it in a transparent layer. The users think that
>   they are clicking visible buttons, while they are actually performing
>   actions on the invisible page. The hidden page may be an authentic
>   page; therefore, the attackers can trick users into performing actions
>   which the users never intended. There is no way of tracing such
>   actions to the attackers later, as the users would have been genuinely
>   authenticated on the hidden page.

Now, Twitter and Facebook has the `X-Frame-Options` set to `'deny'. The console output will prove it.

[image: Console output saying that Twitter has X-Frame-Options set to deny.][Console output saying that Twitter has X-Frame-Options set to deny.]
[image: Console output saying that Facebook has X-Frame-Options set to deny.][Console output saying that Facebook has X-Frame-Options set to deny.]

As we have learned from above, this will prevent CodePen from displaying your Twitter and Facebook pages. Thus, leading to a blank page.

#### References

- [1] - https://techterms.com/definition/iframe
- [2] - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options
- [3] - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking

Comment: Aha! Interesting. I never knew about this. Thank you! So how do you actually change the X-Frame-Options to deny?

Comment: You set it in the backend, either by setting the HTTP headers in your HTTP server (e.g. Apache) or somewhere in your code (e.g. setting it in the views). [This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/167083) can help.